# Extension of quasi-coherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the Hartshorne book (Algebraic Geometry), page 114, we have the following proposition:

**Proposition 5.7**. Let $X$ be a scheme. The kernel, cokernel, and image of any
morphism of quasi-coherent sheaves are quasi-coherent. Any extension of
quasi-coherent sheaves is quasi-coherent. If $X$ is noetherian, the same is
true for coherent sheaves.

My question is: what is an "extension of quasi-coherent sheaves"?

Comment: Doesn't the proof of that proposition make it pretty clear what's meant by "extension"? Often, when I initially have trouble figuring out what part of a theorem means, I can infer it from context by seeing what's actually proved. Does that help here?

Comment: If $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence. $B$ is called an extension of $A$ by $C$.

Comment: @lhl73 that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it as such below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ is a short exact sequence, B is called an extension of $A$ by $C$.